# react native run android stuck on "opening on android..."

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a problem in running my app in the emulator so when I run `npm start` it opens up on browser without any problem but when I press `a` for running on my emulator it stuck at `opening on android...` like below:

[image]

What's the problem? I'm using expo.

Comment: same to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if you ever got a solution, but for me, I changed the virtual device, and it opened the project normally after that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case it happened, because it took ages to download the Expo Client App and you can't see the current download status when running `expo start`.

When you download the expo client via `expo client:install:android` you can see the current status. After the download and install is done, just run your app `expo start` and everything should work fine.